# Opencart - load only some categories?

Tags: opencart, categories

can anybody help me?
Have module. I need load only 10 categories (for example ID 2,5,10,14 etc..).
Here's code:

```
        //categories
        $this->load->model("catalog/category");
        $allCategories = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories(array());
        $categoria_shop = array();

        foreach ($allCategories as $key => $value)
        {
            $categoria_shop[$value['name']] = $value['category_id'];
        }

        $categoria_shop_nezaradene = 69;
```

how can I add ID's of categories

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `catalog/model/catalog/category.php` file, you can see that the function  `getCategories()` has an optional `parent_id` parameter and it must be an `int`, so try this:

```php
// Not tested

$category_ids = array(2, 5, 10, 14);
$categoria_shop = array(array());

foreach($category_ids as $category_id) {
    $categories = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories($category_id);
    foreach ($categories as $key => $value) {
        $categoria_shop[][$value['name']] = $value['category_id'];
    }
}
```

Output example:

```php
$categoria_shop[0]['cat_name2'] = 1;
$categoria_shop[1]['cat_name5'] = 2;
$categoria_shop[2]['cat_name10'] = 3;
$categoria_shop[3]['cat_name14'] = 4;
```

Comment: Have you thought about the performance impact of your code? Also, it has many more or less important errors: **1.** running a SQL request in a loop, **2.** loop in a loop, **3.** `getCategories($category_id)` will load the child categories, you have to call `getCategory($category_id)` instead, **4.** definition `$categoria_shop = array(array());` is incorrect (fills with empty array as first value), **5.** assignment `$categoria_shop[][$value['name']] = $value['category_id'];` creates useless two dimmensional array - it could only be `$categoria_shop[$value['category_id']] = $value['name'];`.

Answer (score 0):

The best option how to load only certain categories is to add a new method to the category model (`catalog/model/catalog/category.php`), let's call it `getMultipleCategories`. It could look like this one:

```php
public function getMultipleCategories($category_ids = array()) {
    if (empty($category_ids) {
        return array();
    }

    $query = $this->db->query("
        SELECT * 
        FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "category c 
        LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "category_description cd ON (c.category_id = cd.category_id) 
        LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "category_to_store c2s ON (c.category_id = c2s.category_id) 
        WHERE c.category_id IN (" . implode(", ", $category_ids) . ")
            AND cd.language_id = " . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "
            AND c2s.store_id = " . (int)$this->config->get('config_store_id') . "
            AND c.status = 1
        ORDER BY c.sort_order, LCASE(cd.name)
    ");

    return $query->rows;
}
```

This method (and it's query) loads all the categories with IDs passed in an array argument (if present).

Now in your controller you can call this method like this:

```php
$categories = $this->model_catalog_category->getMultipleCategories(array(2, 4, 10, 14, 25));
```

It would be better if you could encapsulate this modification (of model) into a vQmod extension so that the method is not gone when you upgrade your OC version.